# Saving to session table in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

My site uses Session and I’ve configured it to save information to the database to allow me to save larger amounts of user data. 
The site also connects to a MySQL and MSSQL database to retrieve information for the user. The Session database is in the MySQL database and this part is working.

The logic of the site goes: 
1. User searches for something, the search button is attached to some jQuery code which sends the search term to 2 functions in my controller.
2. Function 1 accesses the MSSQL database, gets the data, saves the query and the results of the query to the session and returns the query results to the View. 
3. Function 2 does the exact same except it queries the MySQL database.

Function 1 code does this:

```
 $this->session->set_userdata('get_function1_query',$lastquery);
 $this->session->set_userdata('get_function1_result',$query->result_array());
```

Function 2 code does this:

```
 $this->session->set_userdata('get_function2_query',$lastquery);
 $this->session->set_userdata('get_function2_result',$query->result_array());
```

The problem is that the Function 1 code does not save the data to the session table. If I remove the Function 2 code then the Function 1 code works!

Lastly, The result sets of the queries is small. Even so I changed the datatype of the ‘user_data’ field in the ci_sessions table from TEXT to MEDIUMTEXT to allow more information to be stored there.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using the CodeIgniter native session
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session

It appears that there are some issues with Sessions and jQuery in CodeIgniter

Answer (score 1):

When storing data into the session, it must be serialized. the results of $query->result_array() is an array which could pose some trouble when trying to store it as a string.

try calling [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and unserialize to keep keep the data structure intact when pushing things in and out of sessions.

Comment: The Session code within codeigniter handles serialize and un-serialize functions automatically.